# shellcode segmentation fault although assembly works well

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode

I created an assembly program to execute a shell:

```
    section .text
      global _start
    _start:
      xor    eax, eax
      push   eax
      push   0x68732f2f
      push   0x6e69622f
      mov    ebx, esp
      push   eax
      push   ebx
      mov    ecx, esp
      mov    al, 0xb
      int    0x80
```

and since I am working on a 64bit machine, I compiled and linked the program using

```
    nasm -f elf shellcode.asm
    ld -m elf_i386 shellcode.o -o shellcode
```

and produced the shellcode using objdump. The compiled and linked program works absolutely fine. The problem however, is that the shellcode doesn't work in this C program:

```
    // shellcode.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    char shellcode[] =
    "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
     "\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";


    int main()
    {
      fprintf(stdout ,"Length: %d\n", strlen(shellcode));
      (*(void(*)()) shellcode)();
      return 0;
    }
```

I know the shellcode written in the above shellcode array may be wrong, but that's not the case. Even with the right shellcode, the problem persists. Is it a matter of conflict because the architecture? I don't however think so because the program as compiled for 32bit machines and successfully linked, and I know that 64bit machines are backward compatible with 32bit machines. I have tried compiling the C program using the `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack` parameter and disabling ASLR but nothing happened.

Comment: They are backward compatible only in that they can run 32 bit programs. Not 32 bit code embedded in 64 bit program. It's unclear whether you compiled with `-m32` or not. It does work for me, if compiled using `-m32 -z execstack`.

Comment: @Jester Yes that was the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jester Perhaps make it an answer?

Comment: This shellcode won't work on a 64 bit processor because it tries to a) execute a 32 bit system call from a 64 bit process (this might even work!) and b) the stack might be beyond the first 4 gigabytes, causing your `mov ebx,esp` to loose a few bits.